# Facebook Share image thumbnail is not showing up on iPhone

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-opengraph

I have set up the og:image meta tags on my wordpress website and all is working fine, the image thumbnail is showing up on all devices except iPhone, there is no thumbnail there at all. I somehow managed to make it work few days ago, but it appeared blurry, now when I tried to fix that issue the image is gone for good. I used Facebook debug tools and have no errors whatsoever, I don't know what's wrong, maybe I'm missing something here? Thanks for any help.

Here is my code:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://somepage.com/someimage3.png" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="403" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="403" />
<meta property="og:description" content="some description" />
<meta property="og:title" content="some title"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://somepage.com" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to use the absolute path of the image URL.

```
<meta property="og:image:type" content="http://www.somepage.com/images/imageName.png" />
```